# What is the argument type and return type for web elements in qtp?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I keep seeing code like this:

```
.WebButton("locator1", "locator2", "locator3")
```

What is the type of arguments in WebButton, WebElement, WebEdit etc ? I tried passing an array to .WebButton. So, qtp told me its not the correct type. Is there an alternate way to pass multiple locators ?

Also, what is the return type of .WebButton, .WebElement etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

The "arguments" which you are talking about are the set of properties which are needed by QTP/UFT to identify that particular object(WebElement, WebEdit etc.) uniquely so that one can perform actions on them.

Also, this is not some sort of a function that is going to return you any value.

If you are not sure about what properties you need to mention in those brackets, an easier way would be to add that object to the Object Repository and drag that object from OR to your script. After that you can perform any action on those objects.

If you do not want to use OR, then you need to make use of, what we call, Descriptive Programming(DP) wherein you have to mention the object property names and their values "explicitly" in the script.

Remember that the sole purpose of mentioning these properties is to help QTP identify the objects in your application so that you can perform actions on them(like click, set etc.)

Here are a few links which can help you:
http://www.learnqtp.com/descriptive-programming-simplified/

http://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial-6.html

http://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial-32.html

EDIT 2 - for answering your question in the comment:

`.WebButton("Locator1","Locator2","Locator3")` means `.webButton("property1:=value1","property2:=value2","property3:=value3")`

Now, I could have only mentioned property-value pair1(which you are referring to as "Locator1") only If it alone was sufficient for identifying that webbutton. If only 1 property-value pair cannot help UFT in UNIQUELY recognizing the webbutton, then I have to provide another property-value pair until I have provided enough of them so that QTP recognizes that webbutton uniquely. **Since, I have provided multiple property-value pairs(or locators), they have to be separated by commas. If there was only one property-value pair, no comma is needed.** All this explanation only applies to the case when we are using Descriptive Programming. If we are not using Descriptive programming, then in that case the objects and their properties&values are stored in the Object Repository and you just have to mention their logical names(say Button1 as stored in OR) in the script like:

```
.webButon("Button1")
```

To understand more, you need to do some more research on "How object Identification works in UFT/QTP"

Comment: Thanks Kira. I read a bit about descriptive programming. Is there a way to pass multiple locators in a single string rather than many strings separated by comma ?

Comment: Thanks Kira. Going back to my original question about what goes inside the brackets for things like .webButton(xyz). So .webButton is not a function because it returns nothing. Can it accept arguments ? If the xyz is not an argument, then what is it ? Is it an array or such ? If yes, then I can make one array and use the reference to that array in descriptive code. Eg. okBtnLocator = ["locator1", "locator2"]. Then, do .webButton(okBtnLocator).Exist(5) , .webButton(okBtnLocator).click.